# Redirect laravel installation in a subfolder, hiding the subfolder

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let's say i have installed laravel on a subfolder: i placed all the app stuff outside the html root, renamed the "public" directory in "laravel" and moved under the html root.
I can see the app by connecting to www.mydomain.com/laravel
I used the following .htaccess in the root html folder:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravel/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /laravel/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ laravel/ [L]
```

Now i can access my site directly from www.mydomain.com
But i see that i can still access it from www.mydomain.com/laravel ... and since all the links are generated starting from the base url, the menu and every anchor href points to www.mydomain.com/laravel... even the canonical link of the pages contains "laravel".
Questions:

1. is there a way to avoid this??
2. should i worry for this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, you need to configure your hosts. Either `http-vhosts.conf` or `httpd.conf` or similar file.

```
<VirtualHost >
    ...
    <Directory "path/to/your/root/html/laravel">

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So all you need to do is change the directory path to point directly to your laravel folder inside of `html` directory.

If you do that, remove the lines you added in the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravel/
...
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ laravel/ [L]
```

And place the `.htaccess` file back in `laravel` directory so it can serve page directly from there.